# Can we calculate this limit also without DLH?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate the limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2x^{1000}}{e^{2x}+1}}$.

Since we get the undefinite form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ we use the De L'Hospital Rule and we get
\begin{equation*}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2x^{1000}}{e^{2x}+1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left (2x^{1000}\right )'}{\left (e^{2x}+1\right )'}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2\cdot 1000x^{999}}{2e^{2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000x^{999}}{e^{2x}}\end{equation*}

We apply the DLH again and we get 
\begin{equation*}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000x^{999}}{e^{2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\left (1000x^{999}\right )'}{\left (e^{2x}\right )'}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000\cdot 999x^{998}}{2e^{2x}}\end{equation*}

We see that we have to apply the DLH other $998$ times and then we get: 
\begin{equation*}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000\cdot 999\cdot 998\cdot \ldots \cdot 2\cdot 1x^{0}}{2^{999}e^{2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000\cdot 999\cdot 998\cdot \ldots \cdot 2\cdot 1}{2^{999}e^{2x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1000!}{2^{999}e^{2x}}=0\end{equation*}

Is this correct?

Could we calculate this limit also without the De L'Hospital Rule?

Comment: It is fairly well-known that for any $n$, $x^n=o(\mathrm e^x)$ (even in high-school, but without the $o$ notation).

Comment: What you did is correct.

Comment: Ok! Thank you all!! :-)

Comment: BTW, it's L'Hôpital, not De L'Hospital.

Comment: @MaryStar In general, $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\beta}/a^x=0$ for any $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a>1$. Here $\beta=1000, a=e^2$. This fact can be shown using inequalities and basic transformations only.